# How can you create a batch script which runs the user-specified software?

Tags: batch-file

So basically I want to create a batch script that can run any notepad file which the user specifies. I tried this...

```
@Echo Off
SET /P ANSWER=What is the name of the file to open?  
IF /i (%ANSWER%)==('FIND /i "*.txt" %ANSWER%) (goto :Filename)
goto :exit
:Filename
Start *.txt
EXIT
:exit
ECHO FAILLLLLLLL
PAUSE
EXIT
```

The issue here is the first IF statement. I know its wrong. But, I don't know how to specify the entry of any filename. A different way to do this task is also appreciated.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is simply to open a file that the user specifies in Notepad, the following works for me in Windows 7:

```
@echo off

set /P answer=What is the file name? 
if exist %answer% (
    start notepad.exe %answer%
) else (
    echo Unable to locate %answer%
)
```

Comment: Aha. Perfect!!
That was my goal. I was failing at executing the If statements correctly. Thanks.